# Mongoid validation issues.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Haveing a little trouble getting a grasp on mongoid and active record validations.

My Model:

```
    class Project
        include Mongoid::Document

        field :name
        field :public, :type=>Boolean

        #validation
        validates_acceptance_of :public
    end
```

And In my controller I call:

```
    Project.create!(:name => 'Test Project', :public => false)
```

But I keep getting an error that says: Public must be accepted.

Any thoughts on why I am getting this error although I am creating an entry with a boolean in the public field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_acceptance_of):

> Encapsulates the pattern of wanting to validate the acceptance of a terms of service check box (or similar agreement).

The idea is that they have to check the `:public` checkbox and that should result in a true value; but `false` being a non-true value will fail the validation and the validator will tell you that "Public must be accepted".

Maybe you're looking for:

```
Project.create!(:name => 'Test Project', :public => true)
```

The documentation also says:

> This check is performed only if `terms_of_service` is not `nil` ...

And the `terms_of_service` refers to their example. So you could also do this:

```
Project.create!(:name => 'Test Project', :public => nil)
Project.create!(:name => 'Test Project')
```

if you wanted to get an entry in MongoDB that looked like someone slipped past your validations.

Comment: That makes sense, I kept reading it with the mindset of of accepting the value type and not so much relation to a form element.  Although when trying Project.create!(:name => 'Test Project', :public => true) I get the same error.  Really just looking for a way to validate the field type.